# Is there a way to get VS Code to 'Show potential fixes'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

In VS 2017, if I type the following code:

```
public DateTime birth
{  
    get;  
    set;  
}
```

Then I'll get the error:

> The type or namespace name 'DateTime' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and then if I hover over `DateTime` a popup appears `Show potential fixes` and I click `using System;` and it adds this to the top of the class file and the error is resolved.

Is there a way to get VS Code to `Show potential fixes` in a similar way? It doesn't currently seem to suggest any potential fixes (I have `Omnisharp` installed)

Comment: Potential fixes for _what_?

Comment: Potential fixes for error "The type or namespace name 'DateTime' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Those are (showing compile time errors, APIs, etc.) extra additions to VS 2017/15 etc. I think VS code doesn't have these features.

Comment: Didn't you just say yourself that it gave you an option to fix it; to click `using System;`?

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood you.

Comment: @Sach VS 2017 gives the options to fix it, but VS Code does not seem to. My question was whether there was a way to get VS Code to give the options to fix it

Comment: I think the real question is why you are using VSC.  Just use VS Community.  It's free and does a whole lot more     .

Comment: I'm trying to setup Angular 6 with a .NET Core Web API, and many of the online tutorials on the subject are using VSC rather than VS 2017

Comment: VSC aims to be much more "light-weight" than VS, so obviously it doesn't come included with every feature VS has. Extensions are the way to go, you will have to search. Aside from that, use an IDE, not an editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're refering to missing references you can use this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the VSC Extentions. There might be an extension in there that could help you achieve that same functionality as Visual Studio such as [C#](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode) or [C# Extentions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jchannon.csharpextensions)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I already have both of those extensions installed and still no luck

Comment: Why are you using VSC instead of VS though?

Comment: I'm trying to setup Angular 6 with a .NET Core Web API, and many of the online tutorials on the subject are using VSC rather than VS 2017

Comment: I am pretty certain you can achieve the same thing is VS instead of VSC but you will have the fancy "(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score -1):

The following page has different types of formatting extensions you can download for Visual Studio Code: [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VSCode&category=Formatters&sortBy=Downloads)